# retrieving single value from a public method with multiple values c#

Tags: c#

is it possible to have a public method that returns multiple values and then later call that method only retrieving the value that you want?

```
public static string Values()
{
    string length = DAL.Util.getlength();
    string Name = DAL.Util.getName(ddlID.SelectedValue);
    return length + Name;
}
```

now I know if I were to call this method just by saying

```
string a = Values();
```

it would return the concatenated string of both length and Name, but is there anyway to call just a specific variable from that method even if it were 10 variables long?

Thanks for any advice and help you can provide.

Comment: `"but is there anyway to call just a specific variable from that method even if it were 10 variables long?";` I really don't understand what you mean; can you clarify?

Comment: why don't you make a `values` class, with properties for each of the variables you want to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you actually want is a struct (or a class)

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string length
    public string name
}

public static MyStruct Values()
{
    MyStruct result;
    result.name = DAL.Util.getName(ddlID.SelectedValue);
    result.length = DAL.Util.getlength();
    return (result);
}
```

Then you can look at the different elements of the struct as you like.

```
MyStruct data = Values();
Console.WriteLine(data.name);
Console.WriteLine(data.length);
```

Comment: I would *not* use a struct here, and I definitely wouldn't suggest public fields.

Comment: @JonSkeet would you be able to provide an example of using properties as you descrbied? I am not quite sure what I am looking for to find something like that.

Comment: @SteveNicks: It sounds like you should really be reading an introductory book to C#. Stack Overflow is very useful for solving specific problems, but it's not a good place to learn a language from scratch. Books and tutorials are able to teach concepts in a logical progression.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should *actually* be returning a reference to an object which contains the various different bits of state, instead of returning a single string. Then the caller can decide which bits of state they're really interested in, and retrieve those properties directly.

Comment: that does sound like what I would be looking to do, would you by chance have a reference to a site or something where I could take a look at that and give it a try? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object that contains all the values you require.

E.G.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Length { get; set; };
   public string Name { get; set; };
}
```

Then you can return this object from your function:

```
public static MyClass Values()
{
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    MyClass.Length = DAL.Util.getlength();
    MyClass.Name = DAL.Util.getName(ddlID.SelectedValue);
    return MyClass;
}
```

Then you can get whatever properties you require:

```
MyClass myClass = Values();

string name = myClass.Name;
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against passing by reference. Static methods *should not* have side-effects.

Comment: Again, it's not a good idea to have public fields IMO. Use properties instead.